# ExtJs Combobox with multiple values in one selection

Tags: extjs, combobox

I m new to ExtJs. I was wondering if there's some way wherein i can display **multi-line combo-box** in ExtJS in a way that for eg : when i select one item, that item may contain 2 values i.e ID and Name., and both the items are considered as one selection, and not with Ctrl+Select way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure there is. Look at the `tpl` config option of [ExtJS ComboBox](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox). You can define a custom template where you may utilize any fields from the `Store` of the ComboBox as you wish. (See the example included for the `tpl` config option from ExtJS API documentation that I linked.)

Comment: mi : Thanks for the link, I used ` tpl: '<tpl for=\".\"><div ext:qtip="{firstname}.{lastname}" class="x-combo-list-item">{firstname} {lastname}</div></tpl>'` in my xds_index.js class. It works fine. But any way we can display the last name in second line in combo box?

Comment: You will just need to define the HTML markup to split the first and last name on their separate lines... You're free to use virtually any HTML you can come up with inside the template.